# Is it possible to schedule a dynamically created child activity

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

Anyone know if it is possible in a WF4 native activity to schedule a dynamically created child activity? The activity accepts args that determine the child activity to instantiate and run. I've been running into CacheMetadata issues.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible but you could use the InvokeWorkflow / LoadActivity support I built into Microsoft.Activities.  See [How To Invoke a Child Workflow as XAML](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WF4-How-To-Invoke-A-Child-86cc6d31)

Comment: Thanks Ron.
That's similar to the solution I currently employ. However I'd ideally like the child activity to be injected somehow into the existing workflow in order to leverage existing workflow extensions, etc.

Comment: It is not possible to modify the activity tree at runtime.  You could pass extensions to the WorkflowInvoker that invokes the child workflow.

Answer (score 0):

The workflow runtime must know what Activities you are going to run before execution.  So you cannot do the following:

```
protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
{
    context.ScheduleActivity(new MyActivity());
}
```

Unfortunately, the same goes for the Handler of an [ActivityAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.activityaction.aspx) or [ActivityFunc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd486077.aspx).  These must also be set and presented to the runtime during a call to CacheMetadata.

The only possible solution is to implement [IActivityTemplateFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.presentation.iactivitytemplatefactory.aspx) and provide some implementation to your child activity at design time when it is dropped on the design surface, and possibly update your child during calls to CacheMetadata by examining the current workflow and responding accordingly before registering the child with the runtime.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think that would work for activities that are loaded from assemblies discovered at runtime (or from loose XAML). It would be great if it could be done that way however as I'm trying to avoid the WorkflowInvoker route - I want the child activities to be loaded into the existing workflow in order to benefit from extensions etc already loaded.
Examining the current workflow at runtime acting accordingly during CacheMetadata sounds promising though. The activity type to load is set at design time but is not currently loaded until required at runtime.